# Error with my Profile Creation

Tags: support, jobs

I received a Careers 2.0 invitation, and am keen to try it out, but the initial account creation page fails with:

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to
>   log out of your existing account and log back in.

I tried logging out and back in (using Google OpenId), but to no apparent avail. Any ideas?

Comment: This happened to me ages ago, I had to contact Careers support and they fixed it up for me, afaik they can merge the accounts correctly.

Comment: I sometimes really don't understand the voting here: A very valid question gets +1, and a comment/answer to it gets +6. Or is there anything wrong with the question?

Answer (score 4):

we've merged your accounts. For those having the same issue: per Jeremy's comment, just email careers at stackoverflow dot com.